# Storing query results in Redis?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, nosql, redis

I'm trying to store results from my database query into Redis(Redis is behaving here as a cache),I fetch results from DB store procedure into List and then I want to store that list into Redis,how can I achieve this ?

I'm using ServiceStack

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried?  Are you using [ServiceStack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis)?

Comment: Yes I'm using ServiceStack :)

Comment: Can you post any existing code you have that attempts to do this?  It's somewhat beyond the scope of this forum to write up such a module from scratch...

Comment: Hmm,I'm not asking to write module from scratch I'm just asking can I store List object as value in Redis,and get that list from Redis ?

Comment: You sure can :)  Naturally, you'll need to serialize/deserialize as Redis will only accept certain primitives, but that should be simple enough depending on the List object type.  ServiceStack should make this quite painless.

Comment: Ok,I have store procedure in SQL Server that I added in EF,so when calling procedure i get back List<procedrename>,but I can't figure out how to store this into redis ?

Comment: serialize it into json and store json at a key. or you can store the list in a redis list, where each element is, again, a json string representing the corresponding element.